# error invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables:

```
tblDiver:
diver_number int  primary key,
first_name char
last_name char

tblDiving:
diving_number int primary key,
date_of_diving date,
guide(equals to diver_number. a diver can be a guide if he authorized for that)

tblAuthorized:
diver_number,
level_name,
authorization_date

tblParticipate_in:
diver_number
diving_number
```

I want to get a list of all divers (include guides) who didn't authorized in the last year and didn't take a apart in a diving in the last year (not as a guide and not as a diver). I also want to show the number of diving's they had (all time. as a guides and as a divers), and the date of their last diving. If a diver took a part as a diver, he will be in table tblParticipate_in. If he took a part as a guide, he will be in table tblDiving as a "guide". A diver can be authorized to many levels, not only a guide).

I tried this:

```
SELECT tblDiver.diver_number,  tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name,
(select count(*) from tblDiver where tblDiver.diver_number=tblParticipate_in.diving_number  or     tblDiver.diver_number=tblDiving.guide) as Divings_in_past_year,
 max(tblDiving.date_of_diving) as last_Diving
FROM tblDiver, tblDiving,tblAuthorized,tblParticipate_in
WHERE (tblDiver.diver_number not IN((
SELECT tblDiver.diver_number
from tblParticipate_in
where(tblDiving.date_of_diving <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE()) and
tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE()))

union

select tblDiver.diver_number
from tblDiving
where(tblDiver.diver_number=tblDiving.guide and
tblDiving.date_of_diving <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
or tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())))))

group by tblDiver.diver_number,  tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name
```

I'm getting this error.
I'm sure what I did isn't the best way (it's my first time).
Can someone please give me direction to the solution?

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't use a sub-query to get Divings_in_past_year, you have to use an aggregate function.   You could try replacing the sub-query with something like this:

```
SUM(CASE 
  WHEN tblDiver.diver_number=tblParticipate_in.diving_number  or tblDiver.diver_number=tblDiving.guide THEN 1
  ELSE 0 
END) as Divings_in_past_year,
```

Comment: Thank you, You solved the error!!
But now I have an other problem.
It does show the right divers, but the count of Divings_in_past_year is incorrect (everybody get zero, except one who get 150). Also, it shows me the date 2014-08-03 in the last_Diving  to all of divers, while it shouldn't because it in the last year.

Comment: Forget about the part of the date, I think it's ok.
The problem is only with the number of the diving's.

Comment: I think the problem with the number of divings is it is multiplying the number of dives in which they were a guide by the number of times they were just a participant.

Comment: Why are you using "NOT IN..."?   It seems like you would want to get the divers that are IN the subquery, not the ones who are not in it.

Comment: @user3490467

Yes, I think this is the problem. How can I fix it?
And in the last_Diving it's giving me the last date of diving of all divers(it choose the last date of diving in database and add this date to all divers I get in this query), instead of last diving of every diver individually.

Comment: @TabAlleman

No, I want all divers except those who were guide/participate in a divןמע last year

Comment: There are numerous other problems.  Your FROM clause, with all the tables separated by commas means you are not relating the tables to each other.  Also in the first part of your "NOT IN" clause, you are not limiting the rows in tbl_Participate_in in the WHERE clause.  You are using tbl_Diving instead.   So you're getting every row in tbl_Participate_in.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it, it gets ugly though, I'm sure there was an easier way ...

(Edited) I had some typos in my query, fixed now

```
SELECT d.diver_number, d.first_name, d.last_name,
    SUM(s.dive_count) as all_time_total_dives,
    SUM(s.dives_in_last_year) as total_dives_in_last_year,
    MAX(s.most_recent_dive) as last_Dive, 
    t.most_recent_authorization
FROM tblDiver d 
    left join (
        select d1.diver_number, COUNT(*) dive_count, MAX(v1.date_of_diving) most_recent_dive, -- count and date as participant
            SUM(case when v1.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) dives_in_last_year
        from tblDiver d1
        join tblParticipate_in p1 on p1.diver_number = d1.diver_number
        join tblDiving v1 on v1.diving_number = p1.diving_number
        group by d1.diver_number
        union
        select d2.diver_number, COUNT(*) dive_count, MAX(v2.date_of_diving) most_recent_dive, -- count and date as guide
            SUM(case when v2.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) dives_in_last_year
        from tblDiver d2
        join tblDiving v2 on v2.guide = d2.diver_number
        group by d2.diver_number
    ) s on s.diver_number = d.diver_number
    left join (
        select d3.diver_number, MAX(authorization_date) most_recent_authorization
        from tblDiver d3
        join tblAuthorized a on a.diver_number = d3.diver_number
        group by d3.diver_number
    ) t on t.diver_number = d.diver_number
where t.most_recent_authorization is null or t.most_recent_authorization < DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()) -- no authorization in last year, or potentially no authorization
group by d.diver_number, d.first_name, d.last_name, t.most_recent_authorization
having MAX(s.most_recent_dive) is null or MAX(s.most_recent_dive) < DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()) -- no dives in last year or potentially ever
```

(new Edit after recent comment)

```
SELECT tblDiver.diver_number, tblDiver.first_name, tblDiver.last_name,      
    count(distinct tblDiving.diving_number) as number_of_divins,     
    max(tblDiving.date_of_diving) as last_Diving   
FROM tblDiver 
    inner join tblParticipate_in on tblDiver.diver_number=tblParticipate_in.diver_number 
    inner join tblAuthorized on tblParticipate_in.diver_number=tblAuthorized.diver_number 
    inner join tblDiving on tblDiving.diving_number = tblParticipate_in.diving_number
WHERE tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
group by tblDiver.diver_number, tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name
having MAX(tblDiving.date_of_diving) <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
```

The having is like a where, but on the aggregate function.  Give this a try.

Comment: I did some sample data on my computer, found I had some typos in what I had posted, I cleaned those up, and it seems to work.  If still doesn't work for you, then I'm thinking I understood the question wrong and the query is answering the wrong question.  :-)

Comment: I'll try it again, maybe I did something wrong.
Let's say I don't care about the "guide" any more.
I want to display only the divers who didn't participate in a diving and didn't authorized in the last year. Also I want to show the number of diving's they participate in all time, and the date of the last diving of every diver.

What do I need to change in this code? it's showing same count and same date to all of the divers..

Comment: `SELECT tblDiver.diver_number,  tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name,
     count(distinct tblDiving.diving_number) as number_of_divins,
    max(tblDiving.date_of_diving) as last_Diving
 
FROM tblDiver inner join tblParticipate_in on tblDiver.diver_number=tblParticipate_in.diver_number
inner join tblAuthorized on tblParticipate_in.diver_number=tblAuthorized.diver_number,
tblDiving
WHERE ((tblDiving.date_of_diving <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE()) and tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())))
 group by tblDiver.diver_number, tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name`

Comment: You needed condition for the join on tblDiving and you can't have the date_of_diving or else it will ignore dives in the last year, even if a diver had them.

Comment: Too long to put the modified code in the comment, will add to the answer.

Comment: You are brilliant! :)
Can you please explain me this lines: 
`group by tblDiver.diver_number, tblDiver.first_name,tblDiver.last_name
having MAX(tblDiving.date_of_diving) <= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())` 

I didn't understand the Having max. I don't want to ask stupid questions again... :(

Ty very much!

Comment: Group by is used when you want to do a count of something, a maximum, etc.  Having is just like a where clause, just for the counts or maximums or whatever.